# Select the items in Spinner dynamically through code

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-linearlayout, android-spinner

I am working on a project in which I need to dynamically add `TextView` and `Spinner` as well. I was able to add these two things dynamically from my program.

Now when I was trying to select some items in the Spinner, it was not selecting those items.

Does I need to do anything to make that item selected in `Spinner`?

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mapColumns.entrySet()) {

    spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(cont);
    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(cont);

    rowTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    spinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for(String s: entry.getValue().split(",")) {
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","");

        spinnerArray.add(s);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(cont, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);

    rowTextView.setText(entry.getKey());
    rowTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    layout.addView(rowTextView);
    layout.addView(spinner);
}
```

Here `mapColumns` will hev Key-Value pair. So in the Spinner all the items are getting shown from the Value of that map.

**Problem Statement:-**

Now I need to make sure if anybody is selecting any items in the Spinner, it should get selected and visible to naked eye.

How can I do that based on my code. Thanks for the help.

Below is the image-

[image]

Comment: Do you mean visible in Spinner as selected?

Comment: Yes. As soon as I select items in Spinner, I cannot see anything what I selected and also everything looks very light in color. But when I had the same thing getting populated from string.xml file, I was able to see everything and also it was not that much light. I have attached the image as well in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an OnItemSelectedListener to your spinner:

```
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

// add the listener
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Then, implement the listener in your activity:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
```

Comment: Thanks Entreco for the suggestion. My question was after selecting the items from the spinner, that items doesn't get reflected to me as I cannot see by my naked eye. But Toast shows me that I did selected some item.

Answer (score 1):

Try use this code :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(con,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: One quick question, I guess, I have found the problem. Here `con` is `getApplicationContext` so that's why it was not working before. But after making it to `getBaseContext` it started working. Then what's the difference between those two?